# Can't report +1 to gerrit server via jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, gerrit

I tried to build CI on my system. The Jenkins could listen gerrit push event and checkout the code. But jenkins Gerrit-Trigger not reporting +1 verified after successful job run.

There is an error message in Console Output: `ERROR Gerrit response: HTTP method POST is not supported by this URLFinished: SUCCESS`

[image]

```
Versions:
Windows 10
Jenkins 2.263.1
Gerrit 2.10.2
Gerrit Trigger Plugin 2.32.0
Git Plugin 4.5.0
```

[image]

[image]

There are some warning, does it matter?
[image]

My item Gerrit Reporting Values:
[image]

**EDIT**

The Error message doesn't show again after modifying `--message Message` to double quotes (Manage Jenkins > Gerrit Trigger > Gerrit Verified Commands)

**EDIT**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things you should consider:

1. Your Gerrit version is (really) too old, it would be very good if you update to a newer version.
2. Try to uncheck the "Use REST API" option at Manage Jenkins > Gerrit Trigger > Advanced > REST API. Maybe the Gerrit 2.10.2 REST API isn't compatible with the Gerrit-Trigger last version.
3. Do you have the "Code-Review" and the "Verified" labels defined on Gerrit? Does the Gerrit user used by Jenkins have permission to perform the review (-1/+1)?

Comment: I try to uncheck "Use REST API", but nothing change. The Gerrit User can review the code manually. How do I know there are "Code-Review" and the "Verified" labels defined on Gerrit?

Comment: If I uncheck "Use REST API", There are some error within system log, like ""--verified" is not a valid option", ""Successful" is not a valid patch set (1)"

Comment: Gerrit > Project > All-Projects > Access, There is the label "Code-Review" for Non-Interactive Users under "Reference: refs/heads/*", but no label "Verified"

Comment: Clearly you don't have the label "Verified" in your Gerrit, you only can review using the Code-Review label. Remove the "--verified" part of the review command in the Gerrit Trigger configuration (and all other "Verified" related part).

Comment: I remove  "--verified" in Jenkins but still fail. I try ```ssh -v  -p 29418 user@host gerrit review %GIT_COMMIT% --message 'msg from jenkins batch' --code-review 1``` within Execute Windows batch command and it works fine.

Comment: I have this in Gerrit Trigger configuration: gerrit review <CHANGE>,<PATCHSET> --message 'Job finished <BUILDS_STATS>' --code-review <CODE_REVIEW>

Comment: hmm..Nothing change. There is not any error message within console output. Do you use Windows 10? or Linux?

Comment: I use Linux (Ubuntu).

Comment: My colleague use Ubuntu too and he can do code-review via setting jenkins UI. Maybe Windows can't do this? or should setting something else.